# Изучаю JavaScript, возник вопрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

Изучаю JavaScript по книге. И там есть такой пример. Но не работает у меня.

```
    let Car = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

let drawCar = function(car) {
    let carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

    let carElement = $(carHtml);

    carElement.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: car.x,
        right: car.y,
    });

    $('#body').append(carElement);
};

let tesla = new Car(20, 20);
let nissan = new Car(100, 100);
drawCar(tesla);
drawCar(nissan);
```

В HTML только два тега `script`, один для jQuery, а второй для JavaScript.

Comment: А что именно не работает?

Comment: машинка не появляется, я и размеры задал, все равно не сработал

Comment: А точно должно быть `$('#body')`, а не `$('body')`

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже написал в комментариях, скорее всего не работает из-за того, что `.append` применён к `$('#body')`, т.е. к элементу с `id="body"`..
Мне что-то подсказывает, что `.append` по вашей задумке должен быть применён к элементу `<body>`, по этому в `$('#body')` знак `#` лишний.

К тому же, думаю, вы перепутали - вместо `top: car.y` у вас указан `right: car.y`.

```js
let Car = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

let drawCar = function(car) {
  let carHtml = '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYPP5.png">';

  let carElement = $(carHtml);

  carElement.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: car.x,
    top: car.y,
  });

  $('body').append(carElement);
};

let tesla = new Car(20, 20);
let nissan = new Car(100, 100);
drawCar(tesla);
drawCar(nissan);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!